# About finding the inverse of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I am solving a linear algebra problem and this matrix came up from a system of linear equations.

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & \cdots & n \\
1 & 2^2 & \cdots & n^2 \\
\vdots &  & &\vdots &\\
1 & 2^n & \cdots & n^n
\end{pmatrix}
$

I do not know how to check if my system has an unique solution or not (or the matrix is invertible) in this case.

Comment: Have a look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Answer (score -1):

The way to go is to run, say, LU-factorisation using one of broadly available codes allowing evaluation of the matrix condition ratio. Run the program for *n*=2,3,4... to see the pattern. You will probably see that the condition ratio is growing with each next *n* (in numerical sense, the matrix looks "bad" to me in general). As soon as the condition ratio reaches the value of about 10**16, the matrix (and all the others for *n* larger than the found one) is singular in numerical sense, because the computer operates with *double precision* variables, ie. it stores 16 significant digits only.